# how Synchronize database with Context object

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

i take new Context object in main Window so Context object die only when i Close that window

```
     public Main_Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    DataContext DB = new DataContext();
```

my problem is after i created  DataContextDB  if i change the date in database from management studio not changing in DataContextDB  to update the DataContextDB   i must close the window and open it again

example 
1 -create object

```
public partial class  Main_Window: Window
 {
   public Main_Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    DataContext DB = new DataContext();
 }
```

2- select using linq

```
var Q=from a in DB.Employee select new {a.Name};
```

result a.Name "AAAA"

3-change Employee name from management studio to "BBBB"

4- select using linq again

```
var Q=from a in DB.Employee select new {a.Name};
```

result a.Name Stile "AAAA"
why when i changed the Employee name from management studio to "BBBB" not changed in object  DataContext until to close window and open it again
and i have other question when i Create Context object then i load all database in this object?

Comment: The ef datacontext is not designed to be long-lived. It's much better to use as many datacontexts as required in a local scope, wrapped in a `using` statement.

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098143/how-to-clear-the-datacontext-cache-on-linq-to-sql