# In LinqPad how to discard/clear all pending changes to database, LinqToSql DataContext does not have a method

Tags: linq-to-sql, linqpad

Using the amazing LinqPad. Is there a way to clear all pending database changes to the built-in LinqToSql `DataContext` (the `UserQuery` object which is `this`)?

Example LinqPad file, connection to a basic mssql database with `tb_person` table.

```
void Main()
{
   var newRow = new tb_person() {FirstName = "Bob"};
   // do lots of db updates, deletes, inserts....
   tb_persons.InsertOnSubmit(newRow);

   // how to do this, revert all pending Db changes?       
   //this.SomeMethodToDiscardChanges()       
}
```

I found 2 option, neither seems to be ideal, maybe there is a LinqPad specific way outside of LinqToSql?

1. Create a new DataContext, how to do this in LinqPad?
2. `DataContext.Refresh()` method passing  in every added or changed entity, cumbersome!

References
[How to clear the DataContext cache on Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098143/how-to-clear-the-datacontext-cache-on-linq-to-sql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reject all changes in a Linq to SQL's DataContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259219/how-can-i-reject-all-changes-in-a-linq-to-sqls-datacontext)

Answer (score 1):

No guarantees, but you can try

```
this.Uncapsulate().ClearCache();
```

I've used this and it seems to work, but I've never used it on a production database.

Alternatively, you can create a new DataContext using

```
var dc = new TypedDataContext(this.Connection.ConnectionString);
```

but of course you can't assign to `this` which means that you need to be careful to prefix all your queries and references to use dc.

Comment: Thanks @sgmoore will give those suggestions a try